# Segmentation fault - splitting command into tokens

Tags: c, shell, segmentation-fault, pipe, tokenize

The code I am implementing in which I split the command first by pipes then by spaces.

```
int main(){
pid_t pid;
while (1) {
printf("$ ");
char *cmd;
ssize_t size=0;
getline(&cmd,&size,stdin);
if (cmd[strlen(cmd)-1]== '\n') {cmd[strlen(cmd)-1]='\0';}
char** commands = splitter(cmd,"|");
int i=0;
int fd[2],in=0;
while (commands[i+1]!=NULL){
 pipe(fd);
 char **args = splitter(commands[i]," \t");
  pid = fork();
  if (pid==-1) {exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
  else if (pid==0){
   close(fd[0]);
   changeIO(in,0);
   changeIO(fd[1],1);
   execvp(args[0],args);
  }
  else{
   waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
   close(fd[1]);
   close(in);
   in = fd[0];
  }
 i++;
}
char **args = splitter(commands[i+1]," \t");
changeIO(in,0);
execvp(args[0],args);
}
}
```

Here follows the implementation of the functions the code above uses

```
void changeIO(int oldfd,int newfd){  
 if (oldfd!=newfd){  
  dup2(oldfd,newfd);  
  close(oldfd);  
 }  
}  


char** splitter(char* stringToSplit, char* delimiter){  
  char *token;  
  int initial_size = 300;  
  char** args = malloc(initial_size*sizeof(char*));   
  token = strtok(stringToSplit,delimiter);  
  int index = 0;  
  while (token != NULL) {  
    args[index] = token;  
    index++;  
    if (index >= initial_size) {  
      initial_size = initial_size + 100;  
      args = realloc(args,initial_size*sizeof(char*));  
      if (!args) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
    }  
    token = strtok(NULL,delimiter);  
   }  
   args[index] = NULL;  
   return args;  
}
```

Ok executing the code I get a segmentation fault when I enter the command in the user input. Testing various options I came to realize it has something to do with the `char** args` in which I pass the tokens of each commands. I can't understand why this happens since memory is allocated and from what I understand I just point the pointer args to that allocated memory. Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Checked with valgrind. Results below:

```
==3361== Memcheck, a memory error detector  
==3361== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.  
==3361== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info  
==3361== Command: ./mysh3  
==3361==   
==3361== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)  
==3361==    at 0x40AFE97: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:59)  
==3361==    by 0x40ACDD1: getline (getline.c:32)  
==3361==    by 0x80486C4: main (in /home/dimitris/Desktop/mysh3)  
==3361==   
$ ls  
==3361== Invalid read of size 1   
==3361==    at 0x4101CAA: execvpe (execvpe.c:50)  
==3361==    by 0x4101B33: execvp (execvp.c:26)  
==3361==    by 0x804885F: main (in /home/dimitris/Desktop/mysh3)  
==3361==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd  
==3361==   
==3361==   
==3361== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)  
==3361==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0  
==3361==    at 0x4101CAA: execvpe (execvpe.c:50)  
==3361==    by 0x4101B33: execvp (execvp.c:26)  
==3361==    by 0x804885F: main (in /home/dimitris/Desktop/mysh3)  
==3361==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack  
==3361==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but  
==3361==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the  
==3361==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.  
==3361==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.  
==3361==   
==3361== HEAP SUMMARY:  
==3361==     in use at exit: 2,520 bytes in 3 blocks  
==3361==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 2 frees, 4,568 bytes allocated  
==3361==   
==3361== LEAK SUMMARY:  
==3361==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==3361==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==3361==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==3361==    still reachable: 2,520 bytes in 3 blocks  
==3361==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==3361== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory  
==3361==   
==3361== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v  
==3361== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from  
==3361== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)  
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger? If you want us to help please provide an [mcve]. We can't debug incomplete code. For example, what is `cmd`?

Comment: Might be the uninitialized fd[2] array. It could also be a problem with the cmd variable itself, which i cannot see how that is initialized. For errors like this i like http://valgrind.org/ in case you are on Linux. However i agree with @kaylum debugger information is really helpful in understanding your problem :)

Comment: @JacobusConradi I am going to test it with valgrind and update my post. Thanks.

Comment: @JacobusConradi Post updated with results

Comment: `char *cmd;`. You need to init `cmd` to be `NULL`. Because `getline` relies on that. Otherwise `cmd` will likely contain a garbage non-NULL value which will mean `getline` does not allocate memory for you and will write to invalid memory causing a seg fault (or other Undefined Behaviour)

Comment: @kaylum made the change but problem still not fixed. Kind of expected it since if that was the case the code would cause a seg fault long before I reached the pipe implementation point

Comment: Debugging is about fixing one problem at a time. You can be sure that's a major bug you just fixed. But we can't fix all your bugs for you in this forum. Best if you learn to debug effectively yourself. Start by learning to use a debugger. And just running valgrind is not enough. Learn to interpret and act on what it tells you.

Comment: @kaylum I posted on this forum to find out if some logic I am following on the code is wrong. The valgrind check seems to find leaks in the splitter. I tested by deleting all occurences of the `char** args` and its usage inside the code ( this means execvp etc goes). The code although it doesn't work properly as intended it does not throw seg fault even though I still use the splitter to tokenize by pipes in the `char** commands`. So I am in a kind of dead end since I don't know how to work my way around that.

Answer (score 0):

It's an off-by-one array index.

Your while loop finishes with `commands[i+1]` being null. Then you pass it to `splitter`.

Pass `commands[i]` instead.

Answer (score -1):

When strtok() finds a token, it changes the character immediately after the token into a \0, and then returns a pointer to the token.

Comment: found [this](http://www.c-howto.de/tutorial-strings-zeichenketten-stringfunktionen-zerteilen-strtok.html) sample. He uses it pretty much exactly the same

Comment: And??  It would be good to be less cryptic with your answer and more explicit in explaining how that relates to the OP's code.

Comment: I tested the splitter() when I tokenized by pipes before moving on with the code and the tokens are done properly, no segmentation faults and when I follow the exact same method with the second part I get this error.  EDIT: The splitter code is 100% mine nothing to do with the link mentioned above